# pass an element name to another classes method

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have a feature file where I am passing the tab names like Actions,Workorders,notifications tabs to pageobjects class where the tab element and its actions are defined. 
If that tab name is not visible we have to click on arrow button and click on the item . And I named the item as tabNameItem. Not clear on how to add the tab item name in this method. Following method threw an error "Then from the tabs User clicks on "accountWorkOrdersTab"                                  # AccountsPageSteps.from_the_tabs_User_clicks_on_tab(WebElement)
      cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Don't know how to convert "accountWorkOrdersTab" into org.openqa.selenium.WebElement.    Try writing your own converter:  "
**Calling method:**

```
@Then("^from the tabs User clicks on \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void from_the_tabs_User_clicks_on_tab(WebElement tabname) throws Throwable {
    serviceCloudAccountsPageObject.openAccountsTabs(tabname);
}
```

**Action class:**

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//a[@text()='Work Order')]")
public WebElement accountWorkOrdersTab;

@FindBy(xpath = "//span[contains(.,'Work Order')]")
public WebElement accountWorkOrdersTabItem;
```

public void openAccountsTabs(WebElement tabName) {

```
    if(verificationHelper.isDisplayed(tabName)){
        tabName.click();
        System.out.println(tabName.getText() +" tab displayed & is clicked");
    }
    else {

        moreTab.click();
        accountWorkOrdersTabItem.click();
        System.out.println("WorkOrder tab not displayed & is clicked from More tab");

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Dont pass the WebElement in feature file, Just pass the string .
from_the_tabs_User_clicks_on_tab(String tabname)

Based on this string value you can use a case statment and return the webElement.

```
public WebElement returnElement(String tabname) {
    WebElement returnElement = null;


    switch (elementName) {
    case "tabname1":
        returnElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@text()='Work Order')]"));
        break;
    case "tabname2":
        returnElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Wor Order')]"));;
        break;
default:
        break;
    }

    return returnElement;
}
```

With the above code you should get the required web element and you can do your actions on the return Element.

Hope you got the idea.